# Threshold line for nvd3 discrete bar chart

Tags: javascript, angularjs, charts, angularjs-nvd3-directives

I am wondering if the nvd3 discrete bar chart has a threshold line feature available. As far as I researched I didn't have any luck but I am looking for any possible alternatives.

http://cmaurer.github.io/angularjs-nvd3-directives/discrete.bar.chart.html

Thanks.